# WritableWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type even after importing necessary executable JARs

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to create a new excel file using below code. I have added all the necessary JAR files as you can see from import code lines. But I am still seeing the error that "WritableWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type" and "Workbook can not be resolved to a type".

```
package myPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.util.List;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell; 

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow; 

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; 

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; 

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class myClass {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    File eFile = new File ("C:\\Users\\bondrea\\AutomationRelatedFiles\\TrialExcel.xlsx");

    WritableWorkbook FinalExcel = Workbook.createWorkbook(eFile);
}
}
```

Comment: The line `WritableWorkbook FinalExcel = Workbook.createWorkbook(eFile);` looks like JXL (JExcel) code, not Apache POI code.

Comment: so do I need to add any more JAR files?

Comment: Please see the [Apache POI Busy Developers' Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

Comment: Yes I was looking at same link..now i have changed the method and i am using FileOutputStream and its working except that i am not able to open the excel file created, it says file is corrupt.

Comment: I am back to JXL, imported jxl JAR and it works. But the file that is created by both methods give me error while opening them "The file you are trying to open is in different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted." I tried both xls and xlsx formats in code line File eFile = new File ("C:\\Users\\bondrea\\AutomationRelatedFiles\\TrialExcel.xlsx");